# A code for producing system of equations for central difference method

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

I am trying to solve the differential equation $y''(x) = y(x)+\sin[y'(x)]$ numerically over the interval $[0,1].$  Now using central difference method I arrived at the equations of the type
$$ y_k = \frac{1}{h^2+2} \left(y_{k-1} + y_{k-1} - h^2\sin\left(\frac{y_{k+1}-y_{k-1}}{2h}\right)\right) $$

for $k=1,2,\ldots, m-1.$ I am trying to solve for $m=10$ making a system of
equations with $y_0=0$ and $y_{10}=1.$
The issue is I am not able to produce the equations in Mathematica.

```
SysEq[xs_List] := (1/(h^2 + 2) (#[[1]] + #[[3]] - h^2*Sin[(#[[3]] - #[[1]])/(2*h)])) & /@ Partition[xs, 10, 1, {1, 1}];
```

So that I can call it

```
SysEq[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10}]
```

or may be an easy way to create whole system of equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to generate the equations, just use Table command. To solve them is different issue. Since they are non-linear.

$$
y^{\prime\prime}=y+\sin\left(  y^{\prime}\right)
$$

3 point centered difference for $y^{\prime\prime}$ is

$$
y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{n-1}-2y_{n}+y_{n+1}\right)
$$

centered difference for $y^{\prime}$ is

$$
y^{\prime}=\frac{1}{2h}\left(  y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}\right)
$$

The ode becomes

$$
\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{n-1}-2y_{n}+y_{n+1}\right)  =y_{n}+\sin\left(
\frac{1}{2h}\left(  y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}\right)  \right)
$$

let $L=1$ and 11 points. 9 are internal points, and 2 are boundary points. Hence number of intervals is 10.

Therefore $h=\frac{1}{10}$ and $n=0,1,\cdots,10$. Where $y_{0}=0,y_{10}=1$.  For $n=1$

$$
\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{0}-2y_{1}+y_{2}\right)  =y_{1}+\sin\left(  \frac
{1}{2h}\left(  y_{2}-y_{0}\right)  \right)
$$

For $n=2$

$$
\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{1}-2y_{2}+y_{3}\right)  =y_{2}+\sin\left(  \frac
{1}{2h}\left(  y_{3}-y_{1}\right)  \right)
$$

And so on. For $n=9$

$$
\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{8}-2y_{9}+y_{10}\right)  =y_{9}+\sin\left(  \frac
{1}{2h}\left(  y_{10}-y_{8}\right)  \right)
$$

Hence the equations are

\begin{align*}
y_{0}  & =0\\
\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{0}-2y_{1}+y_{2}\right)    & =y_{1}+\sin\left(
\frac{1}{2h}\left(  y_{2}-y_{0}\right)  \right)  \\
\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{1}-2y_{2}+y_{3}\right)    & =y_{2}+\sin\left(
\frac{1}{2h}\left(  y_{3}-y_{1}\right)  \right)  \\
& \vdots\\
\frac{1}{h^{2}}\left(  y_{8}-2y_{9}+y_{10}\right)    & =y_{9}+\sin\left(
\frac{1}{2h}\left(  y_{10}-y_{8}\right)  \right)  \\
y_{10}  & =1
\end{align*}

Code is

```
numberInternalPoints = 9;
h                    = 1/(numberInternalPoints+1); 
y[0]                 = 0; 
y[numberInternalPoints + 1] = 1;

vars = Table[y[n], {n, 1, numberInternalPoints}]
eqs = Table[
   1/h^2*(y[n - 1] - 2 y[n] + y[n + 1]) == 
    y[n] + Sin[1/(2*h)*(y[n + 1] - y[n - 1])], {n,1, numberInternalPoints}];
TableForm[eqs]
```

[image]

9 equations, 9 unknowns.

**Update**

As suggested by user64494 below, FindRoot can be used to solve these equations, and the result agree with `NDSolve`

```
sol = FindRoot[
  eqs, {{y[1], 0}, {y[2], 0}, {y[3], 0}, {y[4], 0}, {y[5], 0}, {y[6], 
    0}, {y[7], 0}, {y[8], 0}, {y[9], 0}}]
data = Table[{n*h, Last@sol[[n]]}, {n, 1, numberInternalPoints}]
data = PrependTo[data, {0, 0}];
data = AppendTo[data, {1, 1}]
```

Gives

```
{{0, 0}, {1/10, 0.0558825}, {1/5, 0.117883}, {3/10, 0.187164}, {2/5, 
  0.265029}, {1/2, 0.352914}, {3/5, 0.452386}, {7/10, 0.565109}, {4/5,
   0.692812}, {9/10, 0.837223}, {1, 1}}
```

And

```
p = ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
ClearAll[y, x]
sol = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == y[x] + Sin[y'[x]], y[0] == 0, 
    y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}];
p2 = Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[p, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: A spot on the Sun: `NSolve[eqs, vars, Reals]` generates "NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve".

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple  `DirectSearch:-SolveEquations([100*(-2*y[1]+y[2]) = sin(5*y[2])+y[1], 100*(y[1]-2*y[2]+y[3]) = sin(5*(-y[1]+y[3]))+y[2], 100*(y[2]-2*y[3]+y[4]) = sin(5*(-y[2]+y[4]))+y[3], 100*(y[3]-2*y[4]+y[5]) = sin(5*(-y[3]+y[5]))+y[4], 100*(y[4]-2*y[5]+y[6]) = sin(5*(-y[4]+y[6]))+y[5], 100*(y[5]-2*y[6]+y[7]) = sin(5*(-y[5]+y[7]))+y[6], 100*(y[6]-2*y[7]+y[8]) = sin(5*(-y[6]+y[8]))+y[7], 100*(y[7]-2*y[8]+y[9]) = sin(5*(-y[7]+y[9]))+y[8], 100*(1+y[8]-2*y[9]) = sin(5*(1-y[8]))+y[9]])` results in

Comment: `[y[1] = 0.558824815612752e-1, y[2] = .117882524237100, y[3] = .187164143110649, y[4] = .265028696216958, y[5] = .352914417317458, y[6] = .452385864615537, y[7] = .565109488648346, y[8] = .692812302307770, y[9] = .837223071943341]`  in a moment.

Comment: `FindRoot[{100 (-2 y[1] + y[2]) == Sin[5 y[2]] + y[1], 
  100 (y[1] - 2 y[2] + y[3]) == Sin[5 (-y[1] + y[3])] + y[2], 
  100 (y[2] - 2 y[3] + y[4]) == Sin[5 (-y[2] + y[4])] + y[3], 
  100 (y[3] - 2 y[4] + y[5]) == Sin[5 (-y[3] + y[5])] + y[4], 
  100 (y[4] - 2 y[5] + y[6]) == Sin[5 (-y[4] + y[6])] + y[5], 
  100 (y[5] - 2 y[6] + y[7]) == Sin[5 (-y[5] + y[7])] + y[6], 
  100 (y[6] - 2 y[7] + y[8]) == Sin[5 (-y[6] + y[8])] + y[7], 
  100 (y[7] - 2 y[8] + y[9]) == Sin[5 (-y[7] + y[9])] + y[8], 
  100 (1 + y[8] - 2 y[9]) == Sin[5 (1 - y[8])] + y[9]}, `

Comment: `{{y[1], 
   0}, {y[2], 0}, {y[3], 0}, {y[4], 0}, {y[5], 0}, {y[6], 0}, {y[7], 
   0}, {y[8], 0}, {y[9], 0}}]` outputs `{y[1] -> 0.0558825, y[2] -> 0.117883, y[3] -> 0.187164, 
 y[4] -> 0.265029, y[5] -> 0.352914, y[6] -> 0.452386, 
 y[7] -> 0.565109, y[8] -> 0.692812, y[9] -> 0.837223}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually solving them using fixed point iteration method. Using a new iteration scheme. I have to convert these equation into a fixed point equations and run through my iteration scheme